# How can I detect the encoding of a file correctly?

Tags: vimrc, encoding

Sometimes I download files in cp1251, cp866, and koi8r encodings, all of which are used to represent Cyrillic characters.

How should I specify them in `set fileencodings=...` so that when I open such a file in Vim, it will detect the encoding correctly?

For example, I tried:

```
setglobal fileencoding=utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=utf8,cp1251,cp866,ucs-2le,koi8r
```

It doesn't really work. Here is the text used for text files and the results of each test:

```
Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей же чаю.

file in cp1251 - encoding is detected correctly
file in cp866  - encoding is detected as cp1251
file in koi8r  - encoding is detected as cp1251
```

Comment: [Answered on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/28779/how-do-i-find-the-encoding-of-the-current-buffer-in-vim) a few years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim uses the first encoding that's considered "valid"; for multi-byte encodings such as UTF-8 this is more or less reliable since many documents are not valid UTF-8 documents (although it can sometimes fail for shorter texts), but for fixed-with encodings such as cp1251, cp866, koi8r you almost always end up with a valid document, which is why Vim selects cp1251. "Valid" in the sense "this is a valid codepoint"; Vim doesn't "know" anything about the text and whether or not you intended to write "д" instead of a "{".

You do have a few options:

- Set the encoding in a modeline; see `:help modeline`.
- Store the encoding in the filename (`hello.cp1251.txt`) and set it with an autocmd. If files with a specific encoding are always in the same directory, then you can use that too. For example:

  ```
  augroup set-encoding
      au BufReadPost *cp1251*      set encoding=cp1251
      au BufReadPost /path/to/dir  set encoding=cp1251
  augroup end
  ```
- A function to change the encoding easily might help (e.g. something [like this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Reload_the_same_file_in_different_encoding)). You could even extend this by showing the results of multiple encodings in splits and allowing you to choose one of them.
- And finally, you could write a more robust "detect encoding" function which does a more thorough analysis of the decoded content; for example if you're dealing with prose you could check that at least 80% of the words appear in a Russian dictionary. I can't really find a plugin that does this already right now, and writing it is a bit beyond the scope of this answer.

  This most likely also won't be 100% foolproof, especially not if you use these encodings for non-prose documents (such as code).

In general, the more encodings you have the harder all of this gets.

Comment: Something else I just thought of: another option might be to use the `file` and/or `iconv` tools, which may have better detection for these files. I'm not sure if they do though

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer is really helpful.

Comment: I think the modeline does not work per se. Once Vim reads the modeline, it already *detected* the encoding. Changing it at that time means you have to re-load the file or it wouldn't have an effect I think